# How can I have different colors for different tabs in SuperTabNavigator.

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How can I have different colors for different tabs in SuperTabNavigator.

Below is the code to my SuperTabNavigator with three tabs:

```
<containers:SuperTabNavigator x="0"
                     y="10"
                     width="100%"
                     height="100%"
                     right="1"
                     top="1"
                     left="1"
                     bottom="1" color="black"
                     creationPolicy="all"
                     id="tab_nav" popUpButtonPolicy="{SuperTabNavigator.POPUPPOLICY_OFF}">
        <mx:Canvas label="My Friends" id="friends_container" width="100%" height="100%"/>
<mx:Canvas label="My Groups" id="groups_container" width="100%" height="100%"/>
<mx:Canvas label="Address Book" id="address_container" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</containers:SuperTabNavigator>
```

I want to have different color for every different tab.

How should I do this.

I know there is a firstTabStyleName and lastTabStyleName: 
is there any way to have the secondTab or the middleTab, anything like that could help me to have different colors on tabs as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I really did not get a very good answer to this. But I found a way that solves my purpose.

```
<containers:SuperTabNavigator x="0"
                 y="10"
                 width="100%"
                 height="100%"
                 right="1"
                 top="1"
                 left="1"
                 bottom="1" color="black"
                 creationPolicy="all"
                 tabStyleName="secondTabGradient"
                 firstTabStyleName="firstTabGradient"                    
                 lastTabStyleName="lastTabGradient"
                 id="tab_nav" popUpButtonPolicy="{SuperTabNavigator.POPUPPOLICY_OFF}">
    <mx:Canvas label="My Friends" id="friends_container" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

So the firstTabGradient get the style for first tab, secondTabGradient for second tab and the lastTabGradient for last tab, which for me is the third tab.

This way get three different colored tabs.

I am still working on the css part. But it is good enough for any references:

```
    <mx:Style>
    .firstTabGradient
    {
        backgroundImage: ClassReference("custom.GradientBackground");
        backgroundSize: "100%";
        background-color: green;
        fillColors: #23b34d, #06832a;
        fillAlphas: 1, 1;           
    }
    .lastTabGradient
    {
        backgroundImage: ClassReference("custom.GradientBackground");
        backgroundSize: "100%";
        background-color: blue;
        fillColors: #028edf, #02bba0;
        fillAlphas: 1, 1;
    }
    .secondTabGradient
    {
        backgroundImage: ClassReference("custom.GradientBackground");
        backgroundSize: "100%";
        background-color: red;
        fillColors: #d70324, #a6001a;
        fillAlphas: 1, 1;
    }

</mx:Style>
```

Thank you
Zeeshan

Answer (score 0):

doesn't look like they have styles for that. You may not be able to have separate styles without doing your own tab bar extension.

Comment: No i know it is possible. Because i have seen it done by someone once.

Comment: not saying it's not possible, just saying they don't have styles set up for it. You would need to extend the control yourself to be able to supply styles for the tabs independently.

Comment: But i can use firstTabStyleName and lastTabStyleName for first and last tab resp. its just about the middle tab. As i have only three tabs, its second tab or middle tab. right?

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at a different superTabNavigator, I'm looking here: http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/flexlib/containers/SuperTabNavigator.html#styleSummary and the only styles they have are for the scroll buttons if your tabs stretch wider than their allotted area.